# How to update the new position of my marker when is moved (dragged)? With React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using React-leaflet to retrieve a position. I created a search input text to place the marker by API address, and I want it to be possible to move the marker more precisely.

I have set the marker to "draggable = true" but I want to update the x and y position and display it in the pop-up window. How to do that please?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import Leaflet from "leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import { MapContainer, Marker, useMap, TileLayer, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'

export default function App(text: any) {
  const [x, setX] = useState(2.3522219)
  const [y, setY] = useState(48.856614)
  console.log(y, x);

  const icon = new Leaflet.DivIcon({
    className: 'custom-div-icon',
    html:
      "<div style='background-color:#c30b82;' class='marker-pin'></div><i class='material-icons'><img src='img/marker-icon.png'></i>",
    iconSize: [30, 42],
    iconAnchor: [15, 42],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -42]
  })

  function SetViewOnClick({ coords }: any) {
    const map = useMap()
    map.setView(coords, map.getZoom())

    return null
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (text.text) {
      setX(text.text.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0])
      setY(text.text.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1])
    }
  }, [text])

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[y, x]}
      attributionControl={false}
      zoomControl={false}
      zoom={12}
      style={{
        height: '350px',
        position: 'relative',
        outline: 'none',
        maxWidth: '696px',
        display: 'block',
        margin: '15px auto',
        width: '100%'
      }}
    >
      <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
      <Marker position={[y, x]} icon={icon} draggable={true}>
        <Popup>
          <span>
            {text.text
              ? text.text.query
              : "Location Default"}
          </span>
        </Popup>
        <SetViewOnClick coords={[y, x]} />
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: You will have to modify the ternary inside the popup because it will not fulfill the condition. You will have 3 cases instead of 2. How would you know which text to show? Unless you want when the marker is dragged to immediately show the new position

Comment: Yes i want immediately show the new position.

Comment: Ok. I thought the same. I wrote an answer. Have a look and let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eventHandlers` on Marker comp in combination with a marker `ref` to update x, y.

```
const markerRef = useRef(null);

  const eventHandlers = useMemo(
    () => ({
      dragend() {
        const marker = markerRef.current;
        if (marker != null) {
          console.log(marker.getLatLng());
          const { lat, lng } = marker.getLatLng();
          setX(lng);
          setY(lat);
          setMarkerDragged(true);
        }
      }
    }),
    []
  );

  ...


 <Marker
    position={[y, x]}
    icon={icon}
    draggable={"true"}
    ref={markerRef}
    eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
  >
    <Popup>
      <span>{popup()}</span>
    </Popup>
    <SetViewOnClick coords={[y, x]} />
  </Marker>
```

You can use also a flag to display the new popup message when the marker is dragged but in the end it depends on you how you would display the popup to evaluate three different conditions.

```
const [markerDragged, setMarkerDragged] = useState(false);
  const popup = () => {
    if (markerDragged) return `New latitude: ${y}, new longitude: ${x}`;
    return text ? text.query : "Location Default";
  };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-update-the-new-position-of-my-marker-when-is-moved-dragged-with-react-leaflet-v3x-qnpgz?file=/src/App.js:2013-2288)